# Why did Apple.SE visitors count drop so fast?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Last month Apple.SE had 1k views/day on average but this week it has decreased to 500. Does anyone knows the reason?

Comment: It's back to ~1K...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect part of it is that it's currently the weekend - there is always a noticeable drop in views on Saturday and Sunday.

However the addition of all the gadgets questions has complicated matters:

> views_per_day there is the sum of all views (as determined by unique IP visits within a reasonable interval) on all questions (including deleted, closed, migrated, etc.) over **the number of days the site has existed (as determined by the creation date of the oldest question)**.

Now that we have much older questions on Apple.SE we have 50 or 60 days at present of very, very few views that previously did not exist at all.

Source: [How is views/day calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64863/how-is-views-day-calculated) on MSO as I believe they adjusted it over this past week.

Comment: Nice catch – migrating questions from Gadgets definitely accounts for a big part of the drop. Oh well, some more [promoting](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89/promoting-apple-se) needed :)

Comment: Of note, the migration of the questions resulted in Apple.SE dropping from 1k to ~513. Whereas Android starts off at a paltry 79 views/day because of it.

Comment: then what we can do to increase it again? must report to development team or something else?

Comment: @Am1rr3zA Just get more visitors and eventually over time the "penalty" will lessen.

Comment: The problem has been fixed! See the linked MSO question for details on how "views per day" is now calculated.